# Is it possible to upload a partial trace in strava?

Tags: strava

I am about to hike 40 days. I already have a smart watch (Huami Amazfit Pace) that communicate with Strava. Thing is I don't know if it is possible to use a single gps for the whole 40 days, pause it every nights, and upload partial activity to strava each night, so that my family can know where I am. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using a single GPS feed is feasible because of battery life of your watch and phone. If you will be having internet every night, you can start the hike on your watch and make sure it it synced with strava and end your daily hike every night.

You can use strava's "beacon" that will send a message to your family while your workout is in progress. https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/224357527-Strava-Beacon